# C++ AVR big code size & excess unused symbols in build file

Tags: avr, c++, compiler, optimization, linker

I'm developing the program for the AVR microcontroller in C++.
I have created a class that contains 8 methods(with constructors) but used only 3.
Class code:

```
class Pin {
    Pin();
    Pin(PinId pin_id);
    Pin(Port port, uint8_t pin);

    void SetDirection(Direction direction);
    Direction GetDirection() const;

    void Write(Signal signal);
    Signal Read() const;

    void Toggle();
};
```

I expect that in the build file unused methods won't be, but it will. I use the `Ghidra` disassembler to disassemble the build file. `Pin(Port port, uint8_t pin)`, `SetDirection` and `Toggle` are used only (simple LED flasher).
But there are all of these methods in the build file and there are no references to these methods. So, why compiler/optimizer/linker doesn't remove these methods from the build file? I compile the program with `-Os` optimization parameter and `Release` CMake configuration.
For example, the `Write` method in the `Ghidra`:
[image]
But the `Write` method isn't used in my code (and in other class' methods too).
How can I optimize it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what file exactly did you analyze? usually, at the end of everything, you might be getting e.g. an ELF file that still contains symbol names, but these would be discarded upon loading the ELF using a debugger into the device's RAM, or during a step that gives you the plain binary. Of course, if you  use C++ and Reflection, or extensive virtual inheritance, you can't throw away any symbols early.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I analyzed the ELF file compiled by `avr-g++`. I don't use virtual functions. Output of `avr-size` is `Program: 682 bytes` and `Data: 0 bytes`

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I just removed a few unused methods from the class and the output from `avr-size` decreased from `682` bytes to `548`.

Comment: yeah, as said, looking at the ELF is **not** the same as looking at what ends up on your microcontroller.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, so, how can I see the size of the program that will end up on the microcontroller? `avrdude` writes as much as the `avr-size` outputs: `avrdude: 548 bytes of flash written`

Comment: to see in more detail the size of functions etc, have it output a .map file

Comment: also, at least in C, to reduce the code size, you have to turn on a couple extra flags in the compiler/linker, most importantly the garbage-collect flag, to trim unused code

Comment: yep, exactly; I know neither avrdude nor avr-size well, but ~550 B for a program that uses C++ sounds pretty slim already. Don't forget that like C, a C++ program needs a runtime, and unlike C, there's a lot more going on in implizit and explicit constructors, destructors, default-initialization …

Comment: @PeteW, my `.map` file: https://pastebin.com/raw/XuczgFXQ. What compiler arguments are you talking about? How can I enable garbage collection?

Comment: Ok so I use C, not C++, and am using GCC, but I believe it will be similar. The following two options were most important: Compiler:  -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections  Linker: -Wl,--gc-sections

Comment: there are some other options, like packing structs, using short (byte) data types for some things. I have found that sometimes, when upgrading the gcc, the code size would go down, though presumably this happens less often as the years go by.

Comment: @PeteW, yeah, it worked, code size reduced to 472 bytes, thanks. You can post the answer if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using GCC (AVR-GCC), the following options can be helpful

Compiler:

-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections

Linker:

-Wl,--gc-sections

---

Additional explanation:

The above options work together as follows

`-ffunction-sections` and `-fdata-sections` -- these put each function or data item into its own section in the output file (i.e. object file coming out of compiler). At this stage it's too soon to say whether we can garbage collect anything, only when linking will there be enough information to make that decision, hence the linker option below

`-Wl,--gc-sections`  -- figures out if there are "sections" that are never used and removes them ("garbage-collection")...

Reference: [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/)

---

Also, examining the .map file is a way to deduce how much individual functions/methods or static data items are contributing to the total size

Comment: Upvoted, but a short explanation what those compiler options actually do, would be nice to complete this answer.

Comment: @Grebu - updated